# debug mono clr with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mono, gdb, clr

I am trying to build mono on windows to debug it later using VisualStudio

is this possible at all?

the compile steps require cygwin and gcc

will they produce data that visual studio debugger can consume?

is there any other way to achieve this?